# Intento ejecutar el comando de instalacion de Angular (npm install -g @angular/cli), he intentado de todo y no he podido avanzar. Anexo imagen del err

Tags: javascript, angular

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco su apoyo. ////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Intentalo con cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ejecutar el comando con privilegios de administrador del equipo.
Ve a la carpeta que te indica e intenta crear ahí un archivo, si te deja reinicia el equipo y vuelve a intentar ejecutar el comando.